# Difference of Squares Oddity

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I was practicing factoring polynomials and ran across a problem I'd never seen before.

$$x^{2m} -36y^2$$

I know this is a difference of squares but I'm not sure how to handle the '$m$' and the reasoning behind it.

By the way, I know what the answer is. I'm not sure on the procedure for handling '$m$' and why.

Comment: See the "Power of a Power Rule" http://mathontrack.comze.com/exponentials2.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that $x^{2m} -36y^2=(x^m)^2 -(6y)^2$

Make the substitution $a=x^m$ and $b=6y$, to get

$a^2 -b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$

Now, back-substitute $a$ and $b$, to get

$x^{2m}-36y^2=(x^m-6y)(x^m+6y)$